# Does it matter how the background image is chosen in a folder?

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering if it matters when you save an image in a folder, like when you right click on an image, Do you choose:"Save link as" or "save image as" as I have tried both but for some reason I cannot display the image as my background for a website. Is there anything wrong with the code that I did? Every time I drag the URL into a new tab or browser I only get 6 bullet points on a blank page.

I mainly used an external CSS sheet, then decided to try to fix it by using an internal sheet on HTML, and since that did not work, instead I tried to implement it in the body tag rather than the header tag but nothing worked. Would I have to use the  tag? But how else will I be able to implement a background?

```
file:///Users/kevinnguyen/Desktop/Screen%20Shot%202019-01-26%20at%2011.09.11%20PM.png
```

The one above is the HTML file.

```
file:///Users/kevinnguyen/Desktop/Screen%20Shot%202019-01-26%20at%2011.12.19%20PM.png
```

this is the external file of CSS.

I'm a new to programming as I self taught myself the basics, yet I want to learn so much of it, it's thrilling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your links to the images don't work because they point to files on your computer. You need to upload them somewhere and put the link here to be able to see them. Anyway, if you have `background-image:url("6928140-swiss-alps.jpg")` your image should be in the same folder as the css file. And it should be called `6928140-swiss-alps` with the `.jpg` extension at the end.